# How to update multiple entities with different random values via JPQL

Tags: jpa, random, jpql, uuid

i need some help in formulating the correct JPQL query in Spring Data with JPA.

The usecase is:
Update a certain attribute of a bunch of Entities with a random value, and for every updated entity the random value must be **different**.

I tried this:

```
@Query("update Entity e set e.randomValue = " + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
void updateRandomValue()
```

This is pure JPQL, but the result is, that every Entity has now the **same** random value.

I could make it work with a native query query, but i really would like to have pure JPQL to be DB independent.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi neil, thanks for correction. actually this is also not correct JPQL as the query must be a constant :-)
I actually thought, that it had worked like my initial version, hm, i have to take a closer look at this again. 
Nevertheless, my question is still valid: how to update multiple entities with random and different values?

Comment: Well I just saw "UUID.randomUUID" and that is not valid JPQL. The only way you can do that with JPQL would be to use "FUNCTION" and specify the function name of an SQL function ... not database-independent really but something to try